# Cannot debug Node.js Google Cloud Functions (local emulator) with VS Code on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to setup the [local emulator for Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) and enable the VS Code debugging features. This is a huge headache and potentially a bug in the functions emulator...

I've followed this guide to the letter: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki/Debugging-with-Visual-Studio-Code.

Local environment:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
- Visual Studio Code 1.13.1 (any 3rd party extensions turned off)
- NVM using Node 6.9.1

Repeatable steps:

**1. Install local emulator for Google Cloud Functions:** `npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator`

**2. Create a basic function:**

```
exports.dbug = (req, res) => {
    var debugTest = 'Breakpoint'
    console.log('Debug breakpoint.')
    res.send('Response success.').status(200)}
```

**3. Start the emulator, deploy the function, test it:** `functions start`, `functions deploy dbug --trigger-http`, `functions call dbug`

[image]

**4. Setup VS Code debugger. launch.json:**

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Debug Functions",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

**5. Start functions debugger:** `functions debug dbug`

**6. Start VS Code debugger:**
[image]

**7. Add breakpoint:**
[image]

**8. Call function:** `functions call dbug`. At this point, terminal sticks, and I have no idea what's going on. It doesn't seem to timeout, so I eventually terminate it. The functions emulator seems to completely hang after this and I have to kill the node.js process manually from task manager.
[image]

---

I've tried some other approaches:

- Restart everything. Then start functions, attach VS Code debugger, call function (don't do `functions debug`. This pauses on a step in net.js for some reason. When I continue, it does not stop at my breakpoint in the function and the function responds normally.
  [image]
- Following this tutorial exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CZ1f6wzn4Q
- Installing and adding @google/cloud-debug doesn't seem to change anything locally.

Comment: Does this tutorial help? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki/Debugging-with-Visual-Studio-Code

Comment: You did resolved this? I think I have the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

For other people seeing this thread. Use `functions inspect myFunc` and run `Debug: Attach to Node Process` in VS Code, attach to the process with the `--inspect` flag and set breakpoints as normal. Run `functions call myFunc` to execute.